# How should I write img.save() so that I can save the images and name them after their index in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, image, function, save, python-imaging-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMF5L.png)
The image_list contains numpy_arrays, and i want to transfer it to image and save them

I wonder if it could be easily work just like this:
im.save(filepath, format='jpeg')  which could simply save the image but naming is still a problem

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The `filepath` contains a full path to the output file, so it also includes a filename. Can you clarify your issue?

Comment: Furthermore, two tips for using Stack Overflow in general: 1) Instead of a sharing an image with a code snippet, share the code snippet as code. 2) Instead of hosting images on an external website, share them on Stack Overflow itself, so they're visible in your post.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [tour] and [mcve] then click [edit] and update your question. Thank you.